# using factory methods with xcode interface builder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, factory-pattern

I have few utility classes in my project which are factory classes that generate UIElements based on few parameters. For example consider this as a very abstract example,

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, MyButtonType)
{
MyButtonRed,
MyButtonBlue,
MyButtonGray,
// ... 

}

@interface MyButtonFactory: UIButton 

+ (UIButton *)buttonWithType:(MyButtonType)type // mybuttontype is an enum which contains various different type of buttons.

@end
```

My question is how do I use this method for UIElements (e.g. buttons in this case) in InterfaceBuilder ?

For non interface builder elements (done in code) I simply use it like this >

```
UIButton *button = [MyButtonFactory buttonWithType:MyButtonRed];
button.frame = (CGRect){ a, b, c, d }; 
// etc
```

Thanks

Comment: Just put a button on your interface builder and change its class to your custom class MyButtonFactory

Comment: Yes, but how do I get the correct button type ? My factory class gives a button based on the type passed into "buttonWithType:" method.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** its unclear what you mean by types. do you mean behavior or simply custom drawing? is there any reason using a custom button cell or subclass doesn't work for you?

You cannot do this directly. (see the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/loadingresources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html))

GUI elements are subclasses of UIView so they will be initialized with a call to `initWithFrame:`

you could implement `initWithFrame` and/or `alloc` to call into the factory, but that seems like poor design.

they will also receive an `awakeFromNib` message. you could tweak your factory to do configuration for elements instead of outright creating them (not really a factory I know). override `awakeFromNib` in a category to have it pass itself to the Configurator.

there are other options depending on what exactly you are trying to do. If all you wanted was to set a custom cell class for all buttons you could do something like this:

```
+ (void)initialize
{
    // force custom button cell class
    [self setCellClass:[CustomButtonCell class]];
}
```

I once wrote a theming engine for AppKit that overrode NSControls `allocWithZone:` method to look up a class replacement, but that isn't a factory and doesn't sound like what you want.

Comment: thanks for your input. basically I've been using this kind of factory classes for theming purposes (not only buttons but textfields) and I'm quite used to it as I've been doing everything in the code. But unfortunately the current project I'm assigned to work on is done fully with IB & I'm trying to find an easier way to apply my usual practices without having to rewrite everything in code. I hope you understand my situation a little better now.

edit : type is a button type defined in the enum (code updated in question)

Comment: I see. so does your factory then actually just apply settings to buttons and such, or do you have subclasses that it uses?

Comment: Not really subclassing, MyButtonFactory is a subclass of UIButton itself & is using a factory method to init and customise various properties based on that (including few custom drawings performed in drawrect, etc). But your first answer kind of guided me into the right direction. I'm going to add in a `setType:(MyButtonType)type` method in my factory class & use code to set it on runtime. I'm sensing it should work without hiccups.

Comment: How are you able to determine how to initialize the button at runtime when loading from a nib? are you hijacking some UIButton property?